# radrails automatically giving me two tabs when i go to new line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radrails

So any time i hit enter and go to a new line... radrails automatically gives me two tabs over. I'd rather turn this off. I haven't been able to figure out how in the settings.

Ideas? thoughts?

is 2 tabs preferred for a specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing auto-indent. I'm not familiar with RadRails, but I would think that you can change some properties to tell it not to auto-indent.

Comment: eh i shouldn't have posted a question about this. thanks for replying at least.